# Css : Border bottom transition issue

Tags: html, css

I tried `CSS` animation to move the `border-bottom` top to bottom on hover. But when I place the cursor on the bottom edge of the border it starts to flicker and the cursor as well as the border continuously changes.

Here is [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/xnf7rws7/1/)

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s;
}

div:hover {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello world
</div>
```

Is there a way to stop the flickering issue Or any other way to get the same animation effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another element, give the outer element a fixed height and make the inner item smaller on hover. I've added the background colors to show what is going on:

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px; /* lineheight+border+padding */
  background: red;
}

div >span{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: yellow;
}

div:hover span{
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
div span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s;
}

div span:hover {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: The border is still flickering.

Comment: apologies, the revised code i have just submitted works. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/billy_farroll/edm2sbp3/

Answer (score 0):

Try using pseudo ::after element instead of the border.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/L9huwv1f/

```
div {
  display: inline;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative
}

div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
div::after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the .5s duration is too long when trying to move 3px.

In this example you can see that a .2s timer is more fluid for your 3px variation and that .5s timer is also fluid when transitioning more pixels

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: inline;
}

div:hover {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div1 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  transition: padding-bottom .2s;
}

.div2 {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transition: padding-bottom .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Hello world 1
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="div2">
  Hello world 2
</div>
```